Unable to upload images to S3 using boto3
I am using fastapi to upload images to my s3 bucket. first i tried presigned url method to upload images from postman and it is working fine. But when i try to directly upload image(size ~7kb) from server using upload_fileobj its taking lot of time and connection timeout error. After spending so much time i could not figure out why please help me with this.
i am running fastapi in my local system with localhost and i am new to s3.
my code:-
from fastapi import FastAPI, UploadFile, File
import boto3

app = FastAPI()

s3 = boto3.client('s3',
    aws_access_key_id='******',
    aws_secret_access_key='********',
    region_name="********")

BUCKET_NAME='*******'

@app.post("/upload")
async def upload(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    if file:
        print(file.filename)
        s3.upload_fileobj(file.file, BUCKET_NAME, file.filename)
        return "file uploaded"
    else:
        return "error in uploading."


Side-note: You might want to try upload_file() rather than upload_fileobj().

i tried it but still taking lot of time and throwing connection timeout, is it related to some s3 permission or network access issue?

Where are you running this code? Are you able to use the AWS CLI to upload a file from the same computer, using the same credentials?

i just tried it, it is taking almost 8mins to upload a image. Like what is the issue? because if i want to use this in production then this is not reliable right? Please help

Where are you running the code? Is it the same place where you ran the AWS CLI upload command and it took 8 minutes?

I ran my code in my local system and to test from aws cli in command line the process I used to upload the file is:-aws s3 cp my-files s3://my-bucket/ and yes this took 8mins

You're using the AWS CLI to upload one 7KB file and it takes 8 minutes? Something is definitely wrong. You can use --debug with the AWS CLI to see what it is doing. You might also want to try via a different network (home vs office vs tethered via your phone). Where are you located and which Region are you uploading to?

i really don't know why, but the same code is now taking just 2-3secs to upload images to s3, Thankyou so much for your time @JohnRotenstein
